# How to encrypt and decrypt object data in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an object with three properties `to name` and `message` .I want to encrypt I want to send `name` and `message` as only one property value .How can get back `name` and `message` from receivers side

// I have object like this

```
const user={
to:1235,
name:"fox"
message:"Hi"
}
```

//I want to send it like this

```
const user={
    to:1235,
    name:"fox&&message:"hii",
    }
```

//How can I get name and message

Comment: Do you want to send data like this? `name: "alice&message:hello world"`

Comment: Yes Awais I want to send like this `name:alice&message:hello world`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily decrypt is by using string manipulation.
first you will get data contained in `name` Post param. Suppose we have data like this in server side.

```
let encoded_data = "alice&message:hello world"
```

We then split this string on `&`

```
let split_data = encoded_data.split('&')
let name = split_data[0] //this contains value alice
```

now will split split_data[1] which contains `message:hello world`

```
let message = split_data[1].split(':')[1]
```